# Set default Value select AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I populate my select with an external json-file. Everything works fine. But how can I set the default value of my select?
I want to set it to "United States", one of my option-value, which is loaded from the json-file countries.json.

I´ve tried to do it like this:

```
 ng-init="selectionCountry = options['United States']
```

or with a no., because the States are on the first position...

```
ng-init="selectionCountry = options[0]
```

But, it do not work. Any tips?

**HTML**

```
<select id="country" class="form-control country" ng-model="selectionCountry">
    <option value="" ng-options="country in data.locations.countries | orderBy:'name'">{{country.name}}</option> 
</select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
.controller('NewInvoiceCtrl', ['$scope', '$translate', '$modal', '$window', '$filter', '$http', '$timeout',
function($scope, $translate, $modal, $window, $filter, $http, $timeout) {

    // load and populate Json in country select
    $scope.data = {
        "locations": {}
    };

    $http.get('l10n/countries.json')
      .then(function(res) {
        $scope.data.locations.countries = res.data;
        $scope.$$phase || $scope.$apply();
        // set default
        $scope.selectionCountry = $scope.data.locations.countries[1];
      });
 }])
```

**EXAMPLE JSON**

```
  {
    "alpha2": "US",
    "alpha3": "USA",
    "countryCallingCodes": [
      "+1"
    ],
    "currencies": [
      "USD"
    ],
    "ioc": "USA",
    "name": "United States",
    "status": "assigned"
  },
```

Comment: The values of your select are the elements of the array `data.locations.countries`. Why do you think setting the selected value to `options['United States']` or `options[0]` would work? Wouldn't it be much more logical to set it to `data.locations.countries[0]`?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your countries.json? I expect I like others an in need of a similar file and maybe we could put one up on github to share & maintain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) directive and run the [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter in the controller instead:

**HTML**

```html
<select id="country" class="form-control country" ng-disabled="!data.locations.countries.$resolved" ng-model="selectionCountry" ng-options="country.name for country in data.locations.countries">
</select>
```

**Controller**

```js
controller("NewInvoiceCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
  $scope.data = {
    locations: {
      countries: []
    }
  };

  $scope.data.locations.countries.$resolved = false;

  $http.get('countries.json').success(function(countries) {
    $scope.data.locations.countries.length = 0;
    Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.data.locations.countries, $filter('orderBy')(countries, 'name'));
    $scope.selectionCountry || ($scope.selectionCountry = $scope.data.locations.countries[1]);
    $scope.data.locations.countries.$resolved = true;
  });
});
```

Additionally, adding a `$resolved` field allows you to disable the field until the countries list has been populated (this is similar to what [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) does).

Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/vuKsqU5q52s7pfOPcGLI?p=preview

---

Alternatively, if you want to select the default based on the name:

```js
$scope.data.locations.countries.$default = 'United States';

// when setting $scope.selectionCountry
$scope.selectionCountry = $filter('filter')($scope.data.locations.countries, {name: $scope.data.locations.countries.$default})[0];
```

Here's an example of the "by name" filter: http://plnkr.co/edit/Czy53cTfptPdyAPBr3eS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this should work. I am not sure why you were calling `$scope.$apply()`

```
$http.get('l10n/countries.json')
  .then(function(res) {
    $scope.data.locations.countries = res.data;
    $scope.selectionCountry = $scope.data.locations.countries[0];
  });
```

Comment: Hi jessegavin, thank you for your solution. Unfortunately, the select remains on first option. And the first (default) option is empty.